# Chrome DevTools Toggle Comment Shortcut not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-deployment

I started to use Chrome workspaces which is an awesome feature. Unfortunately the "toggle comment" shortcut (http://anti-code.com/devtools-cheatsheet/) "Cmd+/" is not working. When I press "Cmd+7" nothing happens or if the "switch panels" is on, then the panels switch. When pressing "Cmd + shift + 7" the help menu shows up from the top bar. How can I fix this. I really need this toggle comment shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with some shortcuts that require to press a modifier key on non-english keyboard. I reported the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=462958).

**Workaround for Windows/Linux :**

If you are using a german keyboard layout, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `*` should do the trick in the meantime. Make sure you use the `*` that is *not* on the numerical keyboard.

**Workaround for Mac OS :**

Use a keyboard layout editor, for example [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele), so as you can output a <kbd>/</kbd> without having to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> or any other modifier key.

Comment: Ok seems to be a similar issue. Ideed I use a German keyboard on a Mac. I still cant't get it to work. Do you have any other "modifier keys" which could work?

Comment: By "modifier key" I did'nt mean the alternative shortcut but instead the `Shift` key we have to press on our layouts in order to output a `/` character. I tested the `Ctrl + *` with a (virtual) german keyboard, it works on windows, but `Cmd + *` indeed doesn't help on a Mac. Anyway, I was able to toggle comment on a mac by remapping the slash character. I used a program called "ukelele" for that.

Comment: this one didn't work for me, i even tried deleting chrome's profile

Answer (score 0):

I just checked that the shortcuts you are trying to use do actually work. I wrote the cheatsheet btw. The shortcuts work when you are using Chrome Canary, and you have to set up a workspace to work on the code that way. Also, Cmd+7 for me jumps to the 7th tab in my DevTools. Perhaps you have some other program overriding the shortcut key for that.

[For more information on workspaces](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces)

There's also a [more comprehensive list of shortcuts here.](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts)